# Object file portability

Tags: compiler-construction

I have an object file file.o compiled for intel 486 and vxworks 5.0 RTOS. I have a couple of questions:

Q1: can this file be linked in an executable to target and run on other CPU architecture like ARM?

Q2: can this file be linked in an executable to target and run on higher models of intel CPU?

Q3: can this file be linked to an executable for target os like micrium or free rtos or higher versions of vxworks?

A detailed solution and suggested portability options are highly appreciated.